# Calling String method in Kotlin when block

Tags: android, kotlin, syntax, kotlin-when

Currently I have a when block like this:

```
val foo = getStringFromBar()

when {
    foo == "SOMETHING" -> { /*do stuff*/ }
    foo == "SOMETHING ELSE" -> { /*do other stuff*/ }
    foo.contains("SUBSTRING") -> { /*do other other stuff*/ }
    else -> { /*do last resort stuff*/ }
}
```

Is there any way to simplify this to something like this:

```
val foo = getStringFromBar()

when (foo) {
    "SOMETHING" -> { /*do stuff*/ }
    "SOMETHING ELSE" -> { /*do other stuff*/ }
    .contains("SUBSTRING") -> { /*do other other stuff*/ }  // This does not work
    else -> { /*do last resort stuff*/ }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`with`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/with.html)

Try this way

```
    with(foo) {
        when {
            equals("SOMETHING") -> println("Case 1")
            equals("something",false) -> println("Case 2")
            contains("SUBSTRING") -> println("Case 3")
            contains("bar") -> println("Case 4")
            startsWith("foo") -> println("Case 5")
            else -> println("else Case")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:-

```
 with(foo) {
    when {
        equals("SOMETHING") -> { //do stuff}
        equals("something",false) -> { //do stuff}
        contains("SUBSTRING") -> { //do stuff}
        contains("bar") -> { //do stuff}
        startsWith("foo") -> { //do stuff}
        else -> { //do stuff}
    }
}
```